# php facebook sdk getuser() returns 0

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook php sdk 3

I am using following code :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => MY_APP_ID,
                'secret' => MY_APP_SECRET,
                'cookie' => true
              ));


$userId = $facebook->getUser();

if(!empty($userId)) {
   echo "This is the user id : " . $facebook->getUser();
}
```

but it is always returning 0, before two days it was working finely but today suddenly it is returning 0, I am not getting why ?

Comment: I would try to update the SDK to the latest version.

Comment: I am using the latest version

Comment: No the latest version is `4.0`

Comment: will it put any side effect on the existing code ?

Comment: I think they might have updated the `getAccessTokenFromCode()` function in the sdk.

Comment: What API version is your app using? (See first tab in app dashboard – unless you explicitly specified an API version somewhere, which I don’t think is even possible with the old SDK, it should be the minimal API version shown there.) If it is v2.3, then @Cyclone might be on to something – with that, they changed the return format for the endpoint used to exchange a code for a token from URL-encoded to JSON. Otherwise, if that’s not it, then you need to give us more details, like how you trigger user login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely update the PHP SDK version, because with the old version the current API changes will probably not be reflected, thus causing problems.